# Quickbooks Merchant Services + Scheduled Payment + Integration with Quickbooks Online Application

Tags: payment-gateway, quickbooks-online

I'm in the process of creating some basic code to interface with QBO & QBMS.  I basically need to create a customer in QBO, and create a recurring payment for them in QBMS via the SDK/API.  What method should I use to create an association between the recurring payment and the customer?  -- I am hoping there is an out-of-the-box way to do this that I am missing.

It *seems* like I am speaking of [reconciliation](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0085_QuickBooks_Windows_SDK/030_qbms/0070_Advanced_Topics/QuickBooks_Integration#QBMS_and_QuickBooks_Online) - however the fact that site says "Desktop and hosted applications can integrate with QuickBooks Online (QBO). However, QBO does not currently support the Reconciliation feature." is a little concerning.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO.  I managed to get through to someone @ Inuit and ask them this question.  TL; DR; No, this isn't possible.

If you'd like to do this, you'll need to use the QBMS API (qbXml) to create the charge.  You will then need to use either IPP or Qbms to interface with QB to create a transaction. There won't be any formal link between the record in merchant services and in quickbooks.  It's a little informal for my tastes.

Answer (score 2):

> What method should I use to create an association between the recurring payment and the customer?

There isn't one. As far as APIs are concerned, the APIs for QuickBooks and the APIs for QuickBooks Merchant Services are entirely independent, and they don't really "interact" with each other in any way.

It would be your application's job to maintain an association between the QuickBooks customer, and the stored "wallet ID" for the credit card information and scheduled billing information. It would also be your application's job to actually push a record of the credit card charge over into QuickBooks for each transaction (e.g. QuickBooks Merchant Services just charges cards, it doesn't push any info into QuickBooks automatically).

We have some wiki info on [QuickBooks Merchant Services integration APIs](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_qbms_integration) on our website.

You can then look into the QuickBooks Online APIs (either [Intuit Anywhere](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0025_Intuit_Anywhere) or the [QuickBooks Online SDK](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_online_edition) to push the data to QuickBooks.

> It seems like I am speaking of reconciliation

Not really. Reconciliation is the process of matching up the payments you recorded in QuickBooks, with the money that actually got deposited into your bank account, less the fees. You can't even do reconciliation without first making the charges and getting the data into QuickBooks somehow.

It's might be worth looking into software out there that is specifically geared towards what you're looking to do - I know at least [ChargeOver does recurring billing and integrates with QuickBooks](http://chargeover.com/).